# Creating a Python Program for Government Data

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a program that performs a calculation using Python objects to represent data. Essentially, I'm trying to figure out what percentage of the
population voted in the previous election. I also want to determine the name of the county
that had the highest voter turnout in a previous election, as well as the percentage of the
population who voted.

```
def highest_turnout(data) :
  class County :
    def__init__(self, init_name, init_population, init_voters) :
      self.name = init_name
      self.population = init_population
      self.voters = init_voters

 return # modify this as needed

# program evaluated using these objects 
allegheny = County("allegheny", 1000490, 645469)
philadelphia = County("philadelphia", 1134081, 539069)
montgomery = County("montgomery", 568952, 399591)
lancaster = County("lancaster", 345367, 230278)
delaware = County("delaware", 414031, 284538)
chester = County("chester", 319919, 230823)
bucks = County("bucks", 444149, 319816)
data = [allegheny, philadelphia, montgomery, lancaster, delaware, chester, bucks]  

result = highest_turnout(data) 
print(result) # prints the output of the function
```

^^^ That's my current code above. I inputted the data and then created a Class for County. I'm having trouble with this part:

- Finding the County that has the highest turnout, i.e. the highest percentage of the
  population who voted, using the objects’ population and voters attributes
- Returning a tuple containing the name of the County with the highest turnout and the
  percentage of the population who voted, in that order (with the percentage
  represented as a number between 0 and 1)

Any help / tips would be much appreciated. Happy to clarify things further in the comments. Thank you so much as I'm new to Python :).

Answer (score 1):

you could sort the data by the highest turnout like this:

```
turnout = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x.voters/x.population, reverse=True)
```

this sorts them in decreasing order, meaning county with the highest turnout would be `turnout[0].name`

output:

```
chester
```

and your desired tuple could be:

```
highest = turnout[0]
print((highest.name, highest.voters/highest.population))
```

output:

```
('chester', 0.7215045058280377)
```

Answer (score 1):

i have created a program which does look a bit complex but once you read through all of it you may be able to understand it.
It isnt a fully completed program but it gets the job done.
i added a few comments here and there to clarify some pieces of code

```
#creating a dictionary to store the country name and its percentage
data = {}
#creating the class county
class County:
    def __init__(self,country,population,voters):
        self.country = country
        self.voters = voters
        self.population = population
        self.sorted_data = ""
        self.formatted_percentage = ""

    def update_data(self):
        #this method calculates the percentages to 2 decimal points and adds the country and percentage to the dictionary
        percentage = self.voters/self.population
        self.formatted_percentage = "{:.2f}".format(percentage)
        #self.formatted percentage basically takes the calculated percentage and changes it to 2 decimal places
        data.update({self.country: self.formatted_percentage})
        #this .update method allows for the country and formatted percentage to be stored in the data dictionary

    def sort_data(self):
        #this is where the actually sorting and printing takes place
        self.sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        #inside the self.sorted data, we are sorting the list, through the sorted method
        # we then put in the parameters that we are using
        #we are using the items in the data dictionary, our key is lamba, 
        #and reverse basically means that the order will start from highest to lowest
        
        print(self.sorted_data)
        #we then print the actual data, if you do not like how it looks when printed, you can simply add a for loop 
        #to loop through the dictionary and print it instead.



allegheny = County("allegheny", 1000490, 645469)
philadelphia = County("philadelphia", 1134081, 539069)
montgomery = County("montgomery", 568952, 399591)
lancaster = County("lancaster", 345367, 230278)
delaware = County("delaware", 414031, 284538)
chester = County("chester", 319919, 230823)
bucks = County("bucks", 444149, 319816)

allegheny.update_data()
philadelphia.update_data()
montgomery.update_data()
lancaster.update_data()
delaware.update_data()
chester.update_data()
bucks.update_data()

allegheny.sort_data()
```

Comment: Hmmm I'm supposed to use the implementation of the “highest_turnout” function so that it does the following:
● First, find the County that has the highest turnout, i.e. the highest percentage of the
population who voted, using the objects’ population and voters attributes
● Then, return a tuple containing the name of the County with the highest turnout and the
percentage of the population who voted, in that order; the percentage should be
represented as a number between 0 and 1

Comment: The above code doesn't use the highest_turnout function. I tried replacing it with the update_data function, but didn't work out haha. Any thoughts on how to approach this?